# Keep only one number in brackets in string with replace()

Tags: jquery

i have a problem i want to delete all text and number except the number in bracket

Example :

```
Bloc d’alimentation 230 V
Référence: 6301-400-8530-MI422
(1)
```

To :

```
(1)
```

You may have an answer to that, thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: If it's only ever the last 3 characters you need, use `slice(-3)`. Otherwise you could use a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *have* to use `.replace`, capture the digit section in a capturing group, while matching everything else in the string, and replace with the first capturing group:

```js
const input = `Bloc d’alimentation 230 V
Référence: 6301-400-8530-MI422
(1)
foo bar`;
const output = input.replace(/.*(\(\d\)).*/s, '$1');
console.log(output);
```

But that's a bit silly, it makes a lot more sense to use `match` to *extract* the match, rather than *replace*:

```js
const input = `Bloc d’alimentation 230 V
Référence: 6301-400-8530-MI422
(1)
foo bar`;
const match = input.match(/\(\d\)/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you  for your fast reply !